# putting segments on a plot with multiple plots and y variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to put arrows on a plot with multiple plots with different y axes? I would like to put arrows across the time series on the same x axis locations but different y locations. I cant just use   "annotate("segment", x = 37, xend = 84, y = 0.0, yend = 0.0,colour = "black", size = 1, arrow = arrow(ends='both'))" because then it puts them at 0 on the y axis for all variables when I actually want to just put the arrows at the bottom of the y axis which is different for every variable.

Current code:

```
fin_plot <- ggplot(melted_data, aes(x = `Distance`, y = value, group = variable)) + geom_line() + theme_bw() + labs(y="", x= "")  +   theme_classic() + theme(text=element_text(size=16,  family="serif", face = "bold", color = "black")) +
  facet_wrap(variable~., scales = "free_y",ncol=2) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 250),labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 1)) + theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = 'black', size = 1)) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_line(colour = "black", size = 1)) + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 0.1))+ theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(.3, "cm")) + coord_capped_cart(bottom='right', left='none', gap = 0.15) + geom_vline(xintercept=c(58, 132, 204, 250, 309), linetype='dashed', col = 'black')
```

Current output

[image]

desired output
[image]

data:

```
melted_data <- structure(list(Distance = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
                                       12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
                                       28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 
                                       44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 
                                       60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 
                                       76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 
                                       92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 
                                       106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 
                                       119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 
                                       132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 
                                       145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
                                       13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
                                       29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
                                       45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 
                                       61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 
                                       77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 
                                       93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 
                                       107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 
                                       120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 
                                       133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 
                                       146, 147, 148, 149, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
                                       14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
                                       30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 
                                       46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 
                                       62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 
                                       78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 
                                       94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 
                                       108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 
                                       121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 
                                       134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 
                                       147, 148, 149, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
                                       15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 
                                       31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 
                                       47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 
                                       63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 
                                       79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 
                                       95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 
                                       109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 
                                       122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 
                                       135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 
                                       148, 149, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
                                       16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 
                                       32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 
                                       48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 
                                       64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 
                                       80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 
                                       96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 
                                       109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 
                                       122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 
                                       135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 
                                       148, 149), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                         3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                         3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                         3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                         3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                         3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                         3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                         3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                         3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                         3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                         4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                         4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                         4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                         4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                         4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                         4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                         4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                         4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                         4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                                                         5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                                                         5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                                                         5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                                                         5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                                                         5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                                                         5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                                                         5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                                                         5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                                                         5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                                                         5L, 5L), .Label = c("Mg", "Mn", "Zn", "Ba", "All"), class = "factor"), 
                          value = c(0.903247645, 0.912560748, 0.896003508, 0.909572697, 
                                    0.883631829, 0.905722594, 0.892465355, 0.909271173, 0.880506202, 
                                    0.889278401, 0.878534542, 0.959209459, 0.913303825, 0.929893977, 
                                    0.97778374, 0.9885554, 0.929716333, 1.028422583, 1.025638955, 
                                    1.011352651, 1.041343955, 1.092562951, 1.129761801, 1.088857171, 
                                    1.107257284, 1.116728405, 1.103053734, 1.041662037, 1.134182243, 
                                    1.104550315, 1.086952767, 1.106004784, 1.057688595, 1.034347579, 
                                    1.04641385, 1.139270945, 1.048446018, 1.033827731, 1.075554754, 
                                    1.029893202, 1.074749532, 1.001626205, 0.977053541, 0.987467665, 
                                    0.999540478, 0.945184816, 0.959677178, 0.962807712, 0.967023936, 
                                    1.024286493, 0.881264816, 0.967181342, 1.000316876, 0.956168258, 
                                    1.003214572, 1.00047837, 0.940103474, 0.929875987, 0.928227112, 
                                    0.982410241, 0.983035162, 0.976666772, 1.019755049, 1.075189042, 
                                    0.975380543, 0.981316782, 0.986876269, 1.026690916, 1.052379934, 
                                    1.001547298, 0.979888683, 1.008209647, 0.976098272, 0.944479556, 
                                    0.996767684, 1.018077758, 1.028862706, 1.08510417, 1.08963868, 
                                    1.048481179, 1.139954126, 1.107066353, 1.122920581, 1.23904326, 
                                    1.19449336, 1.179971969, 1.165865352, 1.068804094, 1.099436469, 
                                    1.073307737, 1.07045113, 1.101007051, 1.011962649, 1.11202545, 
                                    1.097883672, 1.05361424, 0.993283703, 1.046635444, 1.04951188, 
                                    1.055736151, 1.063705172, 0.977095039, 1.015650848, 1.029367222, 
                                    1.003814349, 0.973376993, 1.021665177, 0.925511352, 1.014703757, 
                                    0.933654542, 1.027336075, 0.961163947, 1.022921765, 0.910164297, 
                                    0.937410814, 0.935246588, 0.925900983, 0.934477753, 0.927973832, 
                                    0.946372309, 0.950554394, 0.9386026, 1.000712639, 0.947846812, 
                                    0.953585987, 0.967735737, 0.927914753, 0.943303715, 0.935435884, 
                                    0.987648375, 0.902379461, 0.939086878, 1.018529942, 0.973874968, 
                                    0.974093087, 0.984149676, 0.948669001, 0.934863295, 1.011232041, 
                                    0.942884239, 0.978044788, 1.023700208, 1.011714275, 0.999153709, 
                                    1.06822476, 0.967735328, 1.131133479, 1.011068503, 1.034903609, 
                                    0.086720869, 0.113119382, 0.088197332, 0.081547788, 0.079373211, 
                                    0.07888827, 0.072865285, 0.079637996, 0.066314774, 0.097585729, 
                                    0.185034982, 0.214466904, 0.294317625, 0.481389256, 0.531196058, 
                                    0.715842439, 0.865098887, 0.987242052, 1.081028291, 1.240920518, 
                                    1.313524957, 1.543771699, 1.78495042, 1.746572555, 2.048760527, 
                                    2.101438775, 1.967474033, 2.000286925, 2.014020838, 1.924470659, 
                                    1.75696549, 1.786681246, 1.633290961, 1.455799758, 1.315346538, 
                                    1.435348984, 1.27887702, 1.152818928, 1.095127218, 0.987502349, 
                                    1.062278922, 0.898540082, 0.83617998, 0.889057689, 0.825563648, 
                                    0.788347646, 0.790973555, 0.775541228, 0.815063004, 0.848723108, 
                                    0.66783059, 0.672629631, 0.747809615, 0.72338158, 0.666220438, 
                                    0.664051795, 0.597260657, 0.689282162, 0.663808452, 0.678551141, 
                                    0.672917354, 0.686199986, 0.724202364, 0.746195474, 0.686135659, 
                                    0.654148537, 0.713488795, 0.72446665, 0.699529989, 0.630120423, 
                                    0.661767463, 0.663290351, 0.705879842, 0.709399338, 0.76228353, 
                                    0.714368918, 0.720561695, 0.837036666, 0.923882149, 1.014163852, 
                                    1.221410703, 1.315825246, 1.368054705, 1.641746627, 1.630198312, 
                                    1.698589629, 1.562956393, 1.427322658, 1.53964983, 1.574583495, 
                                    1.527101216, 1.380123116, 1.28649445, 1.29251968, 1.330565441, 
                                    1.317758525, 1.19292313, 1.217953538, 1.218591815, 1.163372928, 
                                    1.091026791, 0.878691182, 0.903966928, 0.917620557, 0.838430901, 
                                    0.825709255, 0.839298558, 0.76309434, 0.97617394, 0.739885015, 
                                    0.822159341, 0.785335779, 0.771926988, 0.766619321, 0.832448556, 
                                    0.733734124, 0.787221188, 0.685452005, 0.740552711, 0.707414697, 
                                    0.781271754, 0.72652958, 0.729470139, 0.71649368, 0.681176551, 
                                    0.683977986, 0.711079301, 0.681092777, 0.747615639, 0.700953146, 
                                    0.692246657, 0.673560118, 0.820384633, 0.740567172, 0.72070082, 
                                    0.795192662, 0.773897168, 0.74552279, 0.735710787, 0.768825863, 
                                    0.746016457, 0.736542042, 0.744507532, 0.784312542, 0.758393534, 
                                    0.7600356, 0.797384742, 0.773626898, 0.744557896, 0.746612627, 
                                    0.818368055, 0.696689824, 0.748702805, 0.717457681, 0.766243608, 
                                    0.805305259, 0.855909762, 0.803357905, 0.889646097, 0.854456208, 
                                    1.067795473, 1.051422575, 1.17061972, 1.138440648, 1.052796919, 
                                    1.040998633, 1.161739158, 1.025956799, 0.971567748, 1.072911493, 
                                    0.952121155, 1.040392714, 1.069745522, 1.068549198, 1.090194087, 
                                    1.214584829, 1.157485471, 1.245813376, 1.336359991, 1.204038397, 
                                    1.126255292, 1.131057736, 0.922042386, 1.037566449, 1.100852394, 
                                    1.121842367, 0.998657748, 1.006938923, 1.002800377, 0.897387497, 
                                    0.93902937, 0.889327622, 0.802133735, 0.855245047, 0.860702407, 
                                    0.704324249, 0.905827093, 0.760155095, 0.760247698, 0.655991619, 
                                    0.677006743, 0.668001976, 0.623410532, 0.569302474, 0.523713794, 
                                    0.690042836, 0.539115342, 0.528696218, 0.57851915, 0.60294784, 
                                    0.581392042, 0.65277069, 0.65620614, 0.625397246, 0.697647782, 
                                    0.6180657, 0.632326126, 0.684659215, 0.606197513, 0.630134281, 
                                    0.637151517, 0.574538208, 0.605993607, 0.533522181, 0.544522236, 
                                    0.577535469, 0.573427383, 0.672984155, 0.735286828, 0.7532343, 
                                    0.881292245, 0.801132661, 1.122761046, 1.137397845, 1.173190388, 
                                    1.138033979, 1.126494557, 1.144871399, 1.087042815, 0.981750792, 
                                    0.992888445, 0.955352455, 1.074357698, 1.027127808, 1.083248059, 
                                    1.010304962, 1.037776316, 1.052809984, 0.959161909, 0.939369893, 
                                    0.932304641, 0.912110856, 1.035278327, 0.825391661, 0.883818816, 
                                    0.880397247, 0.775385156, 0.860535004, 0.75878312, 0.764243502, 
                                    0.788209749, 0.736029937, 0.746966542, 0.762295984, 0.804665042, 
                                    0.797845669, 0.744225613, 0.846139103, 0.806957411, 0.789078125, 
                                    0.912631032, 0.926629248, 0.807376002, 0.795165332, 0.776764645, 
                                    0.811532921, 0.740169463, 0.707007363, 0.764252403, 0.754265833, 
                                    0.656183602, 0.78602999, 0.734580057, 0.756587437, 0.750509131, 
                                    0.727536118, 0.676232276, 0.714439923, 0.720668076, 0.763533465, 
                                    0.60234143, 0.651920197, 0.744086872, 0.633919728, 0.615213712, 
                                    0.705944962, 0.667362984, 0.742636421, 0.742734852, 0.839492568, 
                                    0.743899849, 0.817080816, 0.773569657, 0.735728339, 0.715168283, 
                                    0.78077814, 0.694280484, 0.773303425, 0.768041196, 0.883401699, 
                                    0.818274274, 0.715927964, 0.696938222, 0.832246446, 0.73089346, 
                                    0.790965216, 0.799717389, 0.865896893, 0.946771069, 0.954212275, 
                                    1.023740345, 1.027036123, 1.086336263, 1.064542815, 0.9463809, 
                                    0.924081609, 0.999832641, 0.911277648, 0.922871168, 0.953134033, 
                                    0.786732115, 0.802026729, 0.832863371, 0.863952475, 0.817833153, 
                                    0.748586924, 0.72095701, 0.738213943, 0.672736744, 0.704947698, 
                                    0.531743532, 0.634123809, 0.683548549, 0.733277161, 0.608993729, 
                                    0.752162246, 0.568705823, 0.643172511, 0.597251486, 0.655514695, 
                                    0.583437677, 0.557676441, 0.646713866, 0.527005047, 0.578023512, 
                                    0.576281064, 0.600923204, 0.578475648, 0.551957027, 0.585007991, 
                                    0.623858699, 0.630936819, 0.636198589, 0.565476603, 0.658861425, 
                                    0.577557604, 0.629178306, 0.646092809, 0.566079299, 0.60953767, 
                                    0.680135261, 0.500802233, 0.704656678, 0.61109605, 0.645344144, 
                                    0.667139888, 0.734969576, 0.780062983, 0.783090234, 0.83005691, 
                                    0.905356723, 0.933746319, 0.947613375, 0.923115827, 0.873482691, 
                                    0.746883952, 0.850273618, 0.795256154, 0.800825928, 0.772630039, 
                                    0.749567395, 0.7823457, 0.772609842, 0.736269985, 0.699705666, 
                                    0.716860238, 0.65909369, 0.806743181, 0.604632102, 0.629103485, 
                                    0.669824708, 0.545219042, 0.605081484, 0.545598194, 0.612458887, 
                                    0.640840679, 0.568115521, 0.578270006, 0.642784637, 0.486235168, 
                                    0.608704086, 0.449107996, 0.603056279, 0.573624703, 0.527880861, 
                                    0.479058818, 0.608581986, 0.497792884, 0.736359035, 0.560758315, 
                                    0.59150912, 0.491623628, 0.646548159, 0.559243084, 0.554057512, 
                                    0.542344646, 0.583808567, 0.623315676, 0.521008383, 0.511710892, 
                                    0.633820855, 0.529775704, 0.590383598, 0.500021436, 0.602344336, 
                                    0.499887402, 0.534870849, 0.583225149, 0.623554367, 0.62596102, 
                                    0.585378422, 0.648988779, 0.577416685, 0.632021029, 0.644454559, 
                                    0.684966009, 0.595845502, 2.479315993, 2.683540753, 2.424790513, 
                                    2.556904106, 2.454032378, 2.486582811, 2.485804182, 2.625597071, 
                                    2.444459365, 2.649813652, 2.686066928, 3.124873535, 3.077318299, 
                                    3.297830917, 3.344358668, 3.589441204, 3.566707313, 3.968369009, 
                                    3.932341434, 4.08973781, 4.374551474, 4.54266808, 4.97884528, 
                                    4.932211371, 5.310903272, 5.372904082, 5.231493496, 5.123516042, 
                                    5.393849098, 5.276658613, 4.970827822, 4.972075355, 4.608769407, 
                                    4.214216452, 4.232190208, 4.539424798, 4.266998558, 3.933891331, 
                                    3.898577905, 3.758409871, 3.707152695, 3.544143355, 3.234304675, 
                                    3.312782898, 3.363897722, 3.32751203, 3.063968711, 3.396338279, 
                                    3.110947858, 3.27642981, 2.802338511, 2.972332411, 2.999566144, 
                                    2.860636811, 2.88545135, 2.715249006, 2.805430479, 2.734554555, 
                                    2.721654986, 2.81795618, 2.810857383, 2.829266791, 3.020586802, 
                                    3.108527475, 2.923112037, 2.898589704, 2.977292189, 2.961041296, 
                                    3.065747444, 2.883958043, 2.837869726, 2.918189185, 2.936651583, 
                                    2.760674734, 2.997230073, 2.888064962, 2.972304014, 3.162708107, 
                                    3.42147456, 3.577994842, 3.897689363, 4.134240754, 4.19746467, 
                                    4.937297252, 4.909702892, 4.974867813, 4.740338415, 4.369505261, 
                                    4.634231316, 4.530190201, 4.380129066, 4.246648651, 4.003376949, 
                                    4.261248528, 4.228186763, 4.190890809, 3.896217461, 4.019225536, 
                                    3.980007369, 3.985014169, 3.698733958, 3.417194347, 3.50155334, 
                                    3.527485148, 3.272718395, 3.228503258, 3.353819869, 3.104831527, 
                                    3.419528222, 3.010592683, 3.256523555, 3.020944643, 3.139582776, 
                                    2.872858156, 3.135211633, 3.047270457, 3.038848701, 2.843214189, 
                                    3.123247632, 2.958537301, 3.257263308, 3.138521527, 3.248321146, 
                                    2.963340122, 3.076476029, 2.987721452, 3.004584487, 2.906910601, 
                                    2.973867453, 3.0761696, 2.869900334, 2.78054149, 3.25876542, 
                                    2.978797901, 3.041764942, 3.029872905, 3.052446623, 2.856505763, 
                                    2.9962536, 3.015603327, 3.111149077, 2.9885447, 2.993520426, 
                                    3.176541902, 3.037954707, 2.975005669, 3.278917742, 3.137024394, 
                                    3.117943428)), row.names = c(NA, -745L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: yes. use geom_segment - this allows you to make use of the faceting variable. You will need to pass a data frame with the respective x/xend/y/yend though

Comment: What do you mean by pass a data frame? @tjebo

Comment: see suggestion in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `geom_segment` - this allows you to make use of the faceting variable. You will then want to pass a data frame with the respective x/xend/y/yend.

```r
library(dplyr)
## create a data frame first for the segments
## it makes sense to use the mininimum of your y for each facet
annot_df <- melted_data %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  summarise(y = min(value), yend = min(value), x = 25, xend = 75)
  
ggplot(melted_data, aes(x = Distance, y = value, group = variable)) + 
  geom_line() +
  ## now use the new data frame for geom_segment
  geom_segment(data = annot_df, aes(x = x, xend = xend, y = y, yend = yend), 
               arrow = arrow(ends = "both", length = unit(5, "pt"))) +
  facet_wrap(variable~., scales = "free_y",ncol=2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>